# Lying down or laying down?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-choice, verb-forms, lie-lay-lain-laid

> He was seen [laying or lying] down near the window.

Which is it? Laying is usually used with an object.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> He was seen **laying down** near the window.

You can use laying here as present tense, if he was seen in the process getting on the bed when the observation (He was seen) was made.

> He was seen **lying down** near the window.

He was already on the bed when the observation (He was seen) was made.

Comment: This doesn't seem right to me.  "To lay" is transitive.  The only sense I can make of "laying down near the window" involves duck feathers.

Comment: Well I would say non-standard but not wrong. [*lay*](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=lay) "'lay down' 4. Nonstandard *To lie down*."

Answer (score 8):

if you treat *lay* as the past tense of *lie*, then *lying* should not be used.
The word *lay* itself means to put something down, so using *lay* this way is not correct.

the correct one is "He was seen lying down near the window."

Comment: Note that even native speakers often get this pair of words confused.

Comment: Yep, this is very common.